# Inserting all images into database from a folder without specifying image name or type

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to loop through a folder and get all of the images and load them into a `SQL Server database`; as is; meaning whatever format the image is in.

In my code I have to specify the image name which is a problem, especially because I do not know the name of the images in advance. I also attempted looping through the directory via a `forloop` but that did not work.

Here is the complete code:

```
class Program
{

    string imageFileLocation = @"C:\dev\dbimage\";
    string imageFilePrefix = "test";
    string imageFileType = ".png";
    int numberImageFiles = 1;
    int maxImageSize = 10000;
    SqlConnection conn = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = null;

    private void LoadImages()
    {

        try
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection(@"MyConnectionStuff");
            conn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            PrepareInsertImages();

            for (int i = 1; i <= numberImageFiles; i++)
            {
                ExecuteInsertImages(i);
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    private void ExecuteCommand(string cmdText)
    {
        int cmdResult;
        cmd.CommandText = cmdText;
        cmdResult = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    private void PrepareInsertImages()
    {
        cmd.CommandText = @"insert into ImageTable 
values (@ImageFile, @ImageData)";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@imagefile", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@imagedata", SqlDbType.Image, 1000000);
        cmd.Prepare();
    }

    private void ExecuteInsertImages(int imageFileNumber)
    {
        string imageFileName = null;
        byte[] imageImageData = null;
        imageFileName = imageFilePrefix + imageFileNumber.ToString() 
+ imageFileType;
        imageImageData = LoadImageFile(imageFileName, imageFileLocation, 
maxImageSize);
        cmd.Parameters["@ImageFile"].Value = imageFileName;
        cmd.Parameters["@ImageData"].Value = imageImageData;
        ExecuteCommand(cmd.CommandText);
    }

    private byte[] LoadImageFile(string fileName, string fileLocation, 
int maxImageSize)
    {
        byte[] imagebytes = null;
        string fullpath = fileLocation + fileName;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullpath, FileMode.Open, 
FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        imagebytes = br.ReadBytes(maxImageSize);
        return imagebytes;
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.LoadImages();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

Comment: Use Directory.GetFiles to get filenames in directory.

Comment: I recommend to reconsider why you want to add this images to your database, because if the number of images will increase overtime your DB will get heavy which makes every Backup and Restoration a real pain in the ass. Instead of minutes it could take hours. Also consider SQL Databases aren't build to hold images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate the .png file in a folder like this:

```
foreach(string filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\dev\dbimage", "*.png"))
{

}
```

`filePath` will contain the full path to the file. If you just want to grab the file name without the full path do:

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
```

Both classes `Directory` and `Path` are in the **System.IO** namespace.

Comment: Thanks: MaDe the changes but now I see the application is looking in the wrong unspecified location for the files: Error: `Additional information: Could not find file 'X:\Application\LoadImageToDb\bin\Debug\test1.png'.`.

Comment: It sounds like somewhere you are accessing a file by file name only, instead of the full path. When you do this it is assumed that the file  is in the same folder as your executable, which I am assuming is `X:\Application\LoadImageToDb\bin\Debug`

Comment: Thanks my friend, got it figured out. Thanks again for showing me in the right direction.